# Using variable length pattern matching in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I've been using Neo4j for the past 3 months.

I've built a 10M node graph database.

I've been reading: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/introduction-pattern.html

My goal is to look-up a single node's value by it's property (easy part) and then I need to discover all nodes connected to my look-up node that have a specific edge label. The question I have is I get very different  behavior and I really don't understand why.

Bottom-line is I need a pattern that will allow me to look up Node1 and find every single node connected to that Node1 having a specific edge label and then assign a single identifier value to it (so that I can say this group of 100 nodes is part of ClusterIDGroup1).

Pattern 1

```
MATCH (l:CodeType { id_value : '050001' })-[:IDENTIFIED_BY*]-(m:CodeType)
WHERE 1=1
RETURN *
LIMIT 10000
;
```

Returns: 62 nodes

Pattern 2

```
MATCH (l:CodeType { id_value : '050001' })-[:IDENTIFIED_BY*30]-(m:CodeType)
WHERE 1=1
RETURN *
LIMIT 10000
;
```

Returns: 90 nodes

Pattern 3

```
MATCH (l:CodeType { id_value : '050001' })-[:IDENTIFIED_BY*0..30]-(m:CodeType)
WHERE 1=1
RETURN *
LIMIT 10000
;
```

Returns: 115 nodes

Why would I get 115, 90, and 62 depending on the variable length expression? I would think that 1) * would get me the most nodes 2) *0..30 would get me the second most and 3) *30 would get me the least.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#match-zero-length-paths):

> If the distance between two nodes is zero, they are by definition the
>   same node.

So, to answer your questions:

- In the first query, you are getting every node within every depth, excluding the codeType nodes (no 0 depth).
- In the second one, you get only nodes that are at exactly 30 relations far from your `l` node.
- In the third query, you get more nodes because you also get your codeType nodes, and you also get every nodes having a relation depth from 0 to 30 from your `l` node.

I think that returning only `l` should help you a lot, `return *` is never a good choice in my opinion.

Also, using `WHERE 1=1` is useless in your queries, you can safely remove it.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. One more follow-on question: When I use Pattern 3 and do *0..30 I get 115 nodes returned, whereas if I do *0..50 I get 84 nodes returned. Why do I get less nodes returned for 0..50? Shouldn't I get more nodes?

Comment: Can you please provide a dataset using http://console.neo4j.org/? Should be nice to try it by myself and figure out the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to think how to do that, because my dataset is 10M nodes and since each pattern match is not reproducible (e.g. how do I get all of the nodes in the cluster), how do I do that? Would it be valuable if I provided all of the nodes that appear to be connected by variable length (e.g. 150 nodes) and just provide that example?

Comment: I see that I get back > 10k nodes back in the rows result window in neo4j, but I'm uncertain why I would get back any more than 150...? There are tons of duplicates... THANKS SO MUCH, I owe you!

Comment: Don't forget to tag as answer, to help the other devs who will maybe, one day, have the same problem :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work check this question, everything is in it.